# Restricting access to beanstalk service to cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I have a service deployed on AWS via beanstalk and my UI is deployed via cloudfront. Is there an easy way to restrict access to my service to the cloudfront. I mean is there a way I can restrict access to the service using some ARN as both are deployed on AWS?

Comment: Do you mean you have a single page app served by Cloudfront that uses an api provided by your service running on beanstalk? Or do you have Cloudfront in front of your beanstalk service?

Comment: @cementblocks - We have a single page app served by Cloudfront that uses an api provided by our service running on beanstalk